# Car brakes not working smoothly

Tags: honda, brakes, accord

I have been driving a Honda Accord 2005 for two months now and from the very beginning it felt that the brakes are not smooth. According to the seller the brake pads were new.

The issue is when I start pressing brake slowly, it felt like brakes are not engaging properly and after a moment it seems to apply full braking force all at once (which is very jarring for the car's occupants!)

I have tried to adjust how I apply the brakes myself a lot, but haven't found a way that results in smooth braking.

I've been driving for ~ 3 years and haven't experienced this in any other car so this leads me to think there is a problem with the brakes on this particular car.

So my question is whether this sounds like "normal" behavior for this model of car or whether it indicates a problem with the brakes? If it's a fault what could that fault be?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I am not sure how to help you because you have not asked an actual question. I will say this; you need to get it to the mechanic **NOW**! Do not take chances with brakes. It could result in an accident if you need to brake in an emergency or may fail altogether.

Comment: With the above comment being said, please [edit] your post to include what you did when you "*tried to adjust myself a lot*". How much brake pad is left? Is the fluid level correct in the master cylinder? Any warning lights on?

Comment: Breaks works, problem is it's not smooth.  Every time I press break it result a hard break, which is really annoying. There is no light on dashboard. How to check the fluid level?

Comment: What you have described is the brakes NOT working properly. The fluid level is checked at the master cylinder. If you do not know how to do that, take it to a mechanic.

Comment: Get your car to a mechanic, the brake problem could get worse without warning.

Answer (score 1):

From pedal to wheels, the following faults are possible:

- Air/moisture in brake fluid
- Low brake fluid
- Leak in brake fluid system
- Worn/damaged ABS
- Worn/damaged brake lines
- Ceased caliper
- Warped rotors
- And several more factors including tire wear and suspension damage.

Yes, there is something wrong somewhere in the braking or related systems, no this is not normal. If you don't have the means to do anything about this, take the vehicle to a mechanic immediately.

If you DO have the means to perform service, start by looking up a manual for your year/model/engine/trim and follow instructions for brake service.

Some things you can try without specialized training or tools:

- Checking for leaks
- Checking brake fluid level
- Bleeding air out of the brake lines
- Checking for unusual wear or damage to the brake rotors
- Checking functionality of brake calipers
- Safely checking ABS functionality in an isolated location

It depends on your time and resources, but if you can't identify or repair the cause of the symptoms, take the vehicle to a mechanic immediately.